# CSS: How do I style the first Letter, of the first Link, in the first List?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm not surprised the CSS doesn't work, but I hope you get the idea. There are 2 lists and I'm trying to target the first letter of the first `a` in the first `ul`. In this example that's the B of Beauty Salons. Can I do this with CSS without changing the HTML?

CSS:

```
.tab-pane .category-headings ul:first-of-type a:first-of-type::first-letter {
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="b">
    <div class="container-fluid category-headings">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span11 offset1">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><a href="./beauty-salons-and-therapy/">Beauty Salons &amp; Therapy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="./blinds/">Blinds</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><a href="./book-binders/">Book Binders</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="./bookkeeping-services/">Bookkeeping Services</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><a href="./builders/">Builders</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="./building-plans/">Building Plans</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/a4644b8h/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change a few of those selectors.  You aren't looking for `ul:first-of-type`.  This will select the first `ul` inside each of the `<div class="span4">` divs.  Instead you want to target the first div with `class="span4"`, like so:

```
.span4:first-of-type
```

Next, basically the same thing, you don't want to target `a:first-of-type`, this will select the first `a` tag in each of those `li` elements.  Instead, target the first `li`, like so:

```
li:first-of-type
```

And then target the `a` tag inside that first `li`

So, to put all that together:

```
.tab-pane .category-headings .span4:first-of-type li:first-of-type a::first-letter {

}
```

Also, as Alan mentioned, the parent of the `::first-letter` pseudo-element must be a block-level element, so add

```
.span4 a { /* make this selector as specific as you need it */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And that should do it.  [**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/a4644b8h/8/)

Answer (score 2):

It works if you set the `<a>` tag to be a block display element:

```
.tab-pane .category-headings ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type a:first-of-type::first-letter {
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tab-pane .category-headings ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type a:first-of-type {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is because the `:first-letter` selector will only apply to block elements, and not inline ones.

[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4644b8h/7/).

Comment: that seems to only style the first letter of each list item, rather than just the first letter of the first link in the first list.

Comment: Ah, that's because we're not selecting only the first `<li>`, editing now... or I would if there wasn't an outstanding edit in the queue!

Comment: Add `li:first-of-type` after `ul:first-of-type` and it works.

Comment: @Metzed: Just a note that `:first-of-type` won't select ONLY the first ul, it will select any ul that is the first ul of its parent.  To get ONLY the first ul, you may need jQuery.

Comment: It is, however, working within the context of .category-headings, so should be OK in this example.

Comment: Hi Alan, your last answer styles the first letter of the first link in every list.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted, misunderstood there!